# Notification Sync from Android Phone

Tags: notifications, google-glass

I have a 3rd party app running on my Android phone. This android phone is paired to a google glass thru myGlass app. I receive a push notifications to the 3rd party app running on the phone. But there is no sync of notification to the glass timeline.

How can I sync the notification received for the 3rd party app on Android phone to google glass.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I think the new Notification Sync feature launched by Google may be useful in this case. You set the MyGlass to access your notification and then it will relay your phone notfications to Glass. You can even choose which apps can send notification to Glass. Find More info [here](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+GoogleGlass/posts/FSfaTv9yfbb)